# Write log when call request action in Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring, lombok

I want to write log everytime an action is call. Currently I write the log for every action like this:

```
   public String init() {
            log.info("Init search form"); // I want to log action name (init) here
            return "initSearch";
    }
```

Is there any better way to do that? I'm researching Interceptor but still don't know how to implement

Comment: Do it in constructor of controller class. Additionally you can put more control for selected method calls via custom annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only with interceptors, as you mentioned it yourself.

in order to implement an interceptor you should implement the class [HandlerInterceptorAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/HandlerInterceptorAdapter.html)

and in your spring configuration you should wire the interceptor with your request

```
<interceptors>
    <interceptor>
        <mapping path="/requestpath" />
        <beans:bean class="com.path.YourInterceptorImpl"></beans:bean>
    </interceptor>
</interceptors>
```

alternatively you could read through a pretty good tutorial for using [AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming) in Spring using AspectJ](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-aop-aspectj-annotation-example/)